# artisan commands in laravel 4 not able to load php_mcrypt

Tags: php, laravel, mcrypt

I have been able to setup my laravel but everytime i try executing an artisan command on the command line i get this error

"unable to load dynamic library. " C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/php_mcrypt.dll" - the specified module could not be found

From phpinfo() it is said that mcrypt is enabled

I have tried

adding "extension=php_mcrypt.dll" to my php.ini file as suggested on similar questions but it did not work

what can i do to solve this problem ?

Comment: Do you have the "php_mcrypt" DLL in that folder ?

Comment: Can you show your command from the commandline?

Comment: Check which `php.ini` file you're using by executing something like this: `php -i | find /i "Configuration File"`

Comment: here is the command i was trying to execute "php artisan Usercontroller:make users" as specified in the ebook i was using , im using the php.ini in the bin/php/phpversion folder

Answer (score 0):

Its because your PHP CLI is runing a different config to your PHP which your web server is running.

You need to update both php.ini files to load php_mcrypt.

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
apache2/php.ini
```

and maybe

```
cli/php.ini
```

Comment: I would guess he's using windows in this case.

Comment: i am running on windows 8 , this folders you mentioned do not exist ll i have are dev, ext , zend_ext folders

Comment: WAMP does indeed have 2 different php's, one which is located within the `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apacheX.X.XX\bin` folder which is the one being used by your webserver and one that resides in `C:\wamp\bin\php\phpX.X.XX` which is the one probably being used by your command line.  You can update both when you want to make a change to your PHP settings.